# how can I get my monogame templates back in visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, monogame

When I first installed monogame into Visual Studio 2013, a tab was created in my templates menu which contained several templates. I found an XNA game studio template that I installed to try out, but when I did, the Monogame templates that I had disappeared.

How can I get back these templates?

Answer (score 1):

I would reinstall MonoGame as a first attempt to fix. The latest version of the [MonoGame installer](http://www.monogame.net/) has templates for VS 2013. These templates were added as of version 3.2 ([see release notes](http://www.monogame.net/2014/04/07/monogame-3-2/)).

If you already have a version installed, uninstall that first.